# Convolving a relatively simple function $n$ times.

Tags: real-analysis, integration, convolution

I have been searching but have thus far been unable to find whether there is a formula for convolving a distribution function $n$ times with itself. For example, given $g:\mathbb{R}\to \mathbb{R}$ is integrable and has compact support, is there a relatively neat formula for $g*\overset{n-\text{times}}{....}g$? For example if $g(x)=x^d\chi_{[0,1)}(x)$ where $d\in\mathbb{N}$?

I know about some particular functions who gave known results, mostly arising from probability, but I was wondering whether there is some more general result shich I couldn't find?

Comment: The general "formula" is just that one: $g*\overset{n-\text{times}}{....}g$. You can also take advantage of the Fourier transform (convolution maps to multiplication).

Comment: I suspect that the answer for the example you seek is an inverse Fourier transform of the form $$\frac1{2 \pi} \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} dk \, \left ( \frac{\sin{k}}{k} \right )^n \, e^{-I k x} $$